# Xcode: how to highlight file with compile error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Coming from Eclipse I'm used to seeing file with compile error highlighted (usually with a red marker).

With Xcode there is a different behaviour.

Is there a way (plugin?) to highlight files that contain any error as in image?

[image]

Maybe I have to manage some property in:

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Behaviours -> Build -> Fails
```

But I can't find any.. maybe running any script?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do this. I always double click the error in the issue navigator (CMD-4), that takes you to the file. Is that close enough?

Comment: I know this method and I find it very "expensive", not always usefull

Comment: If you are desperate (and no one else knows a good answer) you can write a Xcode plugin to highlight the files ;) https://github.com/karolkozub/KKHighlightRecentPlugin might be a good place to start.

Comment: THIS is a good tip man! +100